# Protect against cgi-bin/php attacks centos

Tags: php, apache

I am facing some strange attack while I was checking Apache logs:

```
OST /cgi-bin/php?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1
```

How can I prevent from this attack ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the (URL) decoded value:

> POST /cgi-bin/php?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d
>   suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d
>   auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d
>   cgi.redirect_status_env=0 -n

This log entry tells me that an attempt has been made to exploit a [PHP-CGI vulnerability](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1823) from 2012.

It allows the attacker to override specific PHP configurations. In this case, one of the key modifications is to specify "auto_prepend_file=php://input" which will allow the attacker to send PHP code in the request body.

> How can I prevent from this attack ?

Regularly update your web server(s) and its components. It is also possible to prevent this earlier in the network by means of an IDS/IPS, which should detect this signature.